# Renew antivirus vs buy its new CD

Tags: anti-virus

for the past five years, I've been buying a new Kaspersky Anti-virus CD every year. The consistent trash of old discarded CDs is now irritating me.

I always bought new CDs because (1) they had a newer year label (2015->2016->2017) (2) new software UI; but now I wonder that - since these antivirus get their virus definitions update from the internet server - it does not really matter whether I renew the license of the existing edition or buy a new CD.

I am **not comparing the price difference** between the renewal of old edition's license and buying a new copy. I wish to know what all **significant differences in functionality** will there be if I renew the license instead of buying a new edition?

Comment: you don't have to buy physical copies. you can renew your license and download newer versions.

Comment: The newer versions have numerous improvements which are listed by the vendor.  It's more then simply another years license

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't been buying physical software CDs in the last twenty years...

You are correct; when you renew the license, you get to download the latest version of the program, with the new features and UI. No need to buy another CD and re-install the program.

In fact, even if you buy the program CD of the current year, most likely it won't contain the very latest version of the software (as a new release is usually made every few months); so it will anyway need to update itself, upon its first run, by downloading the latest release from the Internet.

The software purchased via Internet and downloaded via a link from Kaspersky's website, and the software distributed on CD, are exactly the same. The only difference is that you're sure the website contains the latest version.

Usually, the purchase of the software gives also you the right to receive AV database updates (several times a day) and the main software update (usually every a few months) during the course of a year. For this reason, it is even more convenient not to have a CD; when the software expires you will be prompted to renew it, and (after you pay) the new version will be automatically downloaded and installed.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Do you have links to some stats on what do people generally do - buy a new cd or renew the license?

Comment: Honestly not -- but you don't need to follow the crowd :) Buying the software from the Internet is probably what you need.